# Flutter how can i make custom stepper for multi-step form?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, mobile

I want to make a multi-step form but i dont want use regular stepper. I want to make it like that : [image]

I tried make it with regular horizontal stepper but its not being as i want and i cant found any informations about it. How can i make it ? And can i add animation when i press Next form for it goes to 2nd page? Thanks for help :)

Comment: You can use Liner percent indicator currentPage/ totalPages (for example: if ur current page is 3 and total page is 4 3/4 = 0.75) in Linear percent indicator

Comment: @TejaswiniDev thanks man. I appreciete it. I will try it now!